# PHP-FPM gives no response, request does not terminate

Tags: php-fpm, fastcgi, php7, not-responding

I'm using PHP-FPM which worked fine until yesterday, now requests do not return any response and keep running indefinitely - or until the client/proxy runs into a timeout. There is a NGINX proxy in front of PHP-FPM, but the error seems to be inside PHP-FPM (connected directly to PHP-FPM to confirm). The server and php logs have zero entries for these requests.

A few very basic scripts (like "print 'hello world';" or phpinfo, even a simple database query) are generally working and return the expected result. But more complex applications such as Typo3 or PHPMyAdmin generally do not produce any output and do not terminate.

On some occassions even the simple scripts do not work and produced the same symptoms. This can be resolved with restarting PHP-FPM, though.

For a few short periods since the problems emerged, all PHP requests worked fine so it doesn't seem to be a permanent thing. But there is nothing in the server or os changing at these moments.

PHP-FPM version: 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out: The reason was the MySQL database server's storage space was filled up with duplicated binary logs. It seems this resulted in never-ending INSERT/UPDATE queries, which I find a bit odd, since I would expect either PHP or MySQL to raise an error in such a case...